# how to get the memory mapping of a function?

Tags: c#

I have of function for which datas seem to get corrupted. To confirm that suspicion and look into it, I'd need to know the location of the function.

Is there a way to know what space in memory is used by a function?

For example 0X00000000 to 0X00002000 if those address would be available.

**System:** Windows 7 and MS VS 2013

Comment: Can you run a debugger? It seems unlikely that you'd need to do a memory dump to fix an error in C#. What are your constraints?

Comment: are you using [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_operating_system)?

Comment: SEHExceptions are generally native exceptions that cannot be mapped to a corresponding managed exception. As such you should debug your process in native or mixed mode to see if you can find the original exception.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Thanks a lot! A detail I forgot to mention : the codes when I run it not in debugger, crashes farther. However in debug mode it crashed sooner, didn't think much about it till now. However now that I enabled Native Mode, it goes farther and I find the crash I wanted! I'd be really curious to know how this option solved the first crash?